# i configuration is not working its jsf java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
2019-09-09 22:28:23 INFO  Version:37 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
2019-09-09 22:28:23 INFO  Version:41 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
2019-09-09 22:28:23 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-09-09 22:28:23 INFO  Environment:342 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2019-09-09 22:28:24 INFO  Dialect:121 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2019-09-09 22:28:24 INFO  LobCreatorBuilder:120 - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2019-09-09 22:28:24 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:68 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2019-09-09 22:28:24 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-09-09 22:28:25 INFO  SchemaExport:344 - HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2019-09-09 22:28:27 INFO  SchemaExport:406 - HHH000230: Schema export complete
2019-09-09 22:28:27 INFO  HibernateTransactionManager:339 - Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@983f21e] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2019-09-09 22:28:28 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'impactAssessmentService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at com.ppt.dao.BaseDao.retrieveAll(BaseDao.java:37)
    at com.ppt.dao.BaseDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$37b0599e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.ppt.dao.BaseDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e086436.retrieveAll(<generated>)
    at com.ppt.service.HolidayService.retrieveAll(HolidayService.java:40)
    at com.ppt.service.HolidayService.getHolidays(HolidayService.java:26)
    at com.ppt.service.HolidayService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$49ceccfd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.ppt.service.HolidayService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bde9e2b5.getHolidays(<generated>)
    at com.ppt.service.ImpactAssessmentService.init(ImpactAssessmentService.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 44 more
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ppt"></context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:admin-config.properties"/>

    <!-- Create Data Source bean -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
                destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="${datasource.url}" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="${datasource.username}" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="${datasource.pwd}" />
<!--         The initial number of connections that are created when the pool is started. -->
<!--         <beans:property name="initialSize" value = "${pool.initialSize}" /> -->
<!--         The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time, or negative for no limit. -->
<!--         <beans:property name="maxActive" value="${pool.maxActive}"/> -->
<!--         The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit. -->
<!--         <beans:property name="maxIdle" value = "${pool.maxIdle}" /> -->
<!--         The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, without extra ones being created, or zero to create none -->
<!--         <beans:property name="minIdle" value = "${pool.minIdle}" /> -->

    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>

            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop> 
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">2</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class ">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</beans:prop> 
               <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">initial_data.sql</beans:prop>

            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>      

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>         

    <!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>admin</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
        <param-value>6</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
        <param-value>6</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.VIEW_SCOPE_MANAGER_MAX_ACTIVE_VIEW_SCOPES</param-name>
        <param-value>6</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>The threshold size in bytes. Must be a number between 0 and 9999. Defaults to 150.
            </description>
            <param-name>threshold</param-name>
            <param-value>200</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>gzipResponseFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--    <filter>
       <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
          <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
       </init-param>      
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping> -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I solved when I removed one of my dependencies. 
In my case I had the hibernate-core and the hibernate-annotations. The second one has a module called 'hibernate3.5.6' (That's where the /classic/Session come from). So it was conflicting with my hibernate-core.

So I recommend you to check your dependencies and remove redundant packages.

Another thing is that hibernate is now in version 5. It would be a good idea to upgrade it.

I hope this was helpful.